# Is there a way to use Spring Security's form-based login through a programmatic POST request?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, spring-security

I'm building a web-app and have chosen Spring for my backend and React for my frontend. I'm using Spring Security to provide authentication and authorisation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/aUrl/**").hasRole(aRole)
                .antMatchers("/anotherUrl/**").hasRole(anotherRole)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((formLogin) ->
                formLogin.permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/login/success")                   
            )
            .logout((logout) ->
                logout.deleteCookies("remove")
                      .invalidateHttpSession(false)
                      .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            );
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
}
```

and I was trying to submit the POST request through the following component:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state =  {
            username: "",
            password: ""
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("username", this.state.username);
        formData.append("password", this.state.password);
        fetch('/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    handleFieldChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({[event.target.id]: event.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
                <Input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" label="Username:" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleFieldChange}/>
                <Input type="text" placeholder="password" id="password" label="Password:" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleFieldChange}/>
                <SubmitButton text="Log in"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I am basically trying to mimic the POST request sent by the browser in the following scenario:

```
            <form method="post" action="/login">
                <label htmlFor="username" >Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="" autoFocus="" />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="" />
                <button type="submit">Log in</button>
            </form>
```

The problem is that the latter works, the former does not. Specifically, I get a CORS policy error message that does *not* show up in the latter case, despite both pages being on the same port (3000), which is separate from the one that hosts the backend (8080) (N.B: I have declared a proxy as per React's indications). I am guessing that the request is somehow built differently, but I cannot imagine there wouldn't be a way to integrate a programmatic POST with Spring Security: am I simply not supposed to use form-based authentication?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Here is my Spring log:

```
2022-10-21 10:03:57.303  INFO 15260 --- [           main] edu.devs.SomeApplication  : Starting SomeApplication using Java 17.0.2 on *** with PID 15260 
2022-10-21 10:03:57.306  INFO 15260 --- [           main] edu.devs.SomeApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-10-21 10:03:58.117  INFO 15260 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Neo4j repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-10-21 10:03:58.218  INFO 15260 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 85 ms. Found 4 Neo4j repository interfaces.
2022-10-21 10:03:59.397  INFO 15260 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-10-21 10:03:59.409  INFO 15260 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-10-21 10:03:59.410  INFO 15260 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-10-21 10:03:59.537  INFO 15260 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-10-21 10:03:59.538  INFO 15260 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2106 ms
2022-10-21 10:04:00.106  INFO 15260 --- [           main] org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory  : Routing driver instance 1107789101 created for server address ***:7687
2022-10-21 10:04:00.803  INFO 15260 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@c9b5a99, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@70be89ec, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3e43f049, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2017f6e6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@d25e878, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5384ce66, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@336f49a1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@2aee0704, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@755a7218, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@58a7dc4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@19a5b637, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@79ca7bea, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5627cb29, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@125f16b2]
2022-10-21 10:04:01.409  INFO 15260 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-10-21 10:04:01.433  INFO 15260 --- [           main] edu.devs.SomeApplication  : Started SomeApplication in 4.607 seconds (JVM running for 5.145)
2022-10-21 10:04:03.901  WARN 15260 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.c.m.DefaultNeo4jIsNewStrategy    : Instances of class edu.devs.domain.Student with an assigned id will always be treated as new without version property!
2022-10-21 10:04:04.059  WARN 15260 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.c.m.DefaultNeo4jIsNewStrategy    : Instances of class edu.devs.security.UserAuthority with an assigned id will always be treated as new without version property!
2022-10-21 10:04:04.441  WARN 15260 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.c.m.DefaultNeo4jIsNewStrategy    : Instances of class edu.devs.domain.Admin with an assigned id will always be treated as new without version property!
2022-10-21 10:04:05.052  WARN 15260 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.c.m.DefaultNeo4jIsNewStrategy    : Instances of class edu.devs.domain.School with an assigned id will always be treated as new without version property!
2022-10-21 10:04:05.264  WARN 15260 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.c.m.DefaultNeo4jIsNewStrategy    : Instances of class edu.devs.domain.Classroom with an assigned id will always be treated as new without version property!
2022-10-21 10:04:29.586  INFO 15260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-10-21 10:04:29.587  INFO 15260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-10-21 10:04:29.588  INFO 15260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

and here is my browser console log:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/login/success' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

LoginForm.js:26          GET http://localhost:8080/login/success net::ERR_FAILED 302
```

all of which does not show up if I just use a declarative POST.

For good measure, I'm also including the request headers of both.

Here are those of the programmatically-sent request:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 256
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZva4mpEReAgtMlLA
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/login
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

and here are those of the one handled by the browser (the one that works no problem):

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/login
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Obviously I can see that the issue with the former request is that the server redirects the browser to a resource located on a different port, thus triggering a CORS policy error. What I do not get is why this does not happen with the latter request, although I'm guessing it's got something to do with the request headers(?).

Comment: please show your logs, both spring debug logs, and browser consol logs, also you can use the `FormData` object to create formdata instead of building your own string https://javascript.info/formdata#sending-a-form-with-blob-data

Comment: Hi and thanks! Switched to FormData and added the logs as requested